# Magento coupon code doesn't calculate anything

Tags: magento

I have a problem with magento coupon code, I've set up the shopping cart price rule for 10% off all products, but on checkout, when I enter the coupon code and click apply, the page refreshes but nothing is deducted from the price, can anyone help me solve this issue please, I've been looking around for a solution for a few days now, still no luck,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that in Rule Information it's Active and that all main customer groups are checked, and that the from and to dates are covering today (as you are testing it today).

You don't need any Conditions for a blanket 10% off rule but your Action tab should have;

1. The Apply set to 'Percent of product price discount'
2. Discount amount set to 10.
3. Maximum Qty and Discount Qty both set to 0.

And the 'Apply the rule' conditions all blank.

Sorry if this all seems obvious and isn't helping, I have a store with a working 10% off everything and these settings all make it happen. Best of luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, the apply coupon code still doesn't calculate the discount, it shows the total amount, has anyone else had the same problem.

Comment: We are encountering the same issue with some configurable products.